# C# Get element of List where value of List in List matches

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a problem. In my C# code I have a `List<Set> lstSets`. Inside a Set I have another `List<Picture> Pictures`.
The picture class looks like this:

```
public class Set
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Picture> Pictures{ get; set; }
}
```

And the picture class looks like this:

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a random picture where I know the Id and Name, but I need to get the `Index` of the Picture inside the `Pictures` list and I need to know the Set `Id`.

I know the code how I can get something out of one list:

```
myList.FindIndex(a => a.prop == prop);
```

But this is a list in a list.

So I want:

```
int SetId = ....
int PictureIndex = ....
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to use LINQ?

Comment: `set.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Pictures.Any(p => p.Id == picture.Id));` Will return the first set that has a matching picture id in it's `Pictures` list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `Linq` expression returns an `Id` of a `Set` by picture `Id` by using [`FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) methods. If there is no such item, the index is set to `0` using [null coalescing operator `??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

```cs
var setId = lstSets.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Pictures.Any(p => p.Id == pictureId))?.Id ?? 0;
```

This code can be used to get an index of image inside `Pictures` collection of a `Set`

```cs
var index = 0;
foreach (var set in lstSets.Where(set => set.Pictures.Any(p => p.Id == pictureId)))
{
    index = set.Pictures.FindIndex(p => p.Id == pictureId);
}
```

It attempts to find an index of picture inside every `Set` object. There is also an option to look through all `Pictures` of all `Set` items using [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) method

Comment: I see you setting `SetId`, how where are you setting `PictureIndex`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this;

```
int setId = -1;
var picIndex = -1;
foreach (var set in lstSets)
{
    picIndex = set.Pictures.FindIndex(p => p.Id == picToFind.Id && p.Name == picToFind.Name);
    if (picIndex > -1)
    {
        setId = set.Id;
        break;
    }
}
```